# CMake: How to reuse an object files for the tests subdirectory project?

Tags: c++, cmake

My project is something like this:

```
project
├── test
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── test_class1.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── ...
├── class1.h
└── class1.cpp
```

I want to reuse class1.o which was compiled for project binary.
Default CMake behavior compiled it twice for test too.
I try to use OBJECT library but it puts all objects in this library variable. Then compiler print

> main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of `main'

It means that 2 different main.o in one target. And all other *.o files from main project compilation are.

How to exlude unneeded *.o files?

Comment: Can you post your `makefile`?

Comment: *OBJECT* library should definitely help. If not, provide `CMakeLists.txt` where you use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I normally do is that I separate the application logic into a static library (subdirectory), which is then used by both the main application and the tests.

You could keep it in a single dir as well, but then you still need to exclude the main.cpp when building the object library, because otherwise you will indeed have multiple definitions of `main` when building tests (as defined in both main.cpp and the test main).

If you are listing the files explicitly (which is [highly recommended for CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18538444/1274747)), you can simply omit the main.cpp from the list. If you use globbing to list the files, you can remove the file from the list as described here: [How do I exclude a single file from a cmake `file(GLOB ... )` pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550777/how-do-i-exclude-a-single-file-from-a-cmake-fileglob-pattern)

Comment: This. Compile your classes into libraries if you want to easily reuse them throughout the project.

Comment: I decide to use "list operations".

First I added all main project sources to SRC_LIST:

`aux_source_directory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} SRC_LIST)`

Then I exclude some sources to object library for make them shared:

`set(SHARED_SRC
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/event_bus.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/event.cpp)
list(REMOVE_ITEM SRC_LIST ${SHARED_SRC})
add_library(TESTING_OBJECTS OBJECT ${SHARED_SRC})`

Now I can use this precompiled objects both in main project and tests like this:

`set(SRC_LIST ${SRC_LIST} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:TESTING_OBJECTS>)`