# cmake - list does not recognize sub-command FILTER

Tags: cmake

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.5.2

list(FILTER HEADERS EXCLUDE REGEX "^\\..+")

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (list):
  list does not recognize sub-command FILTER
```

Is it problem with version I am using?

Its on ubuntu. Its the latest version one gets from the official ubuntu repository.

Its working fine on Mac with version 3.6.2

What is the least cmake version that offers this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is to be expected, `list(FILTER` was introduced in CMake 3.6.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/list.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/list.html

Comment: Why does sudo apt-get install cmake says I have the latest cmake 3.5.1 version then? ._.

Comment: Because you are using an almost five years old Ubuntu? https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/cmake

Comment: Alright, yes. That was the problem. Although If I hadn't tried to install the new version of cmake on the obsolete x32 bit linux virtual machine, I wouldn't have known isn't supported anymore.