# how to use EXCLUDE REGEX for multiple files in cmake

Tags: cmake

Refer to this:
[How do I exclude a single file from a cmake `file(GLOB ... )` pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550777/how-do-i-exclude-a-single-file-from-a-cmake-fileglob-pattern/15551302)

How to exclude multiple files in a single exclude regex command?

Thank You

Comment: `in a single` But why not multiple?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I have like a lot of files and writing a single command makes it look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to exclude multiple files in a single exclude regex command?

Simply write a regex that matches multiple files. Remember about double escaping in CMake.

```
list(FILTER lib_srcs EXCLUDE REGEX "^(file1|file2|file3)$")
```

Consider doing a function (untested, written here):

```
function(exclude_from_lsit list)
   foreach(ii IN LISTS ARGV)
       list(REMOVE_ITEM ${list} ${ii})
   endforeach()
   set(${list} ${${list}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
exclude_from_list(lib_srcs
   file1
   file2
   file3
)
```

or just a loop really:

```
foreach(ii IN ITEMS
    file1
    file2
)
     list(REMOVE_ITEM lib_srcs ${ii})
endforeach()
```