# Arduino cmake build system without IDE

Tags: c++, c, cmake, arduino

I am trying to build an Arduino project using CMake instead of the Arduino IDE. I understand that i have to link all the C and CPP files in the avr core except for main, so I've renamed `/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/main.cpp` to `main.cc` and I have the following CMake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(HAVE_FLAG_SEARCH_PATHS_FIRST 0)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER avr-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER avr-g++)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED 1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DF_CPU=16000000 -D__AVR_ATmega16U2__=1 -mmcu=atmega2560 -O2")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-DF_CPU=16000000 -D__AVR_ATmega16U2__=1 -mmcu=atmega2560 -O2")

file(GLOB SOURCES "/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/*.cpp" "/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/*.c" "main.cpp")

#list(FILTER SOURCES EXCLUDE REGEX "*main\\.cpp")
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/49377205/983556

#list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES "main.cpp")

#file(GLOB SOURCES "./*.cpp")
add_definitions(-D__AVR_ATmega16U2__)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCES})

# changes c++ standard from gnu++YEAR to c++YEAR
# seems to fix issues using bear and clangd
set_target_properties(untitled PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

target_include_directories(untitled PUBLIC "/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/libraries/EEPROM/src/")
target_include_directories(untitled PUBLIC "/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/")
target_include_directories(untitled PUBLIC "/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/variants/standard")
target_include_directories(untitled PUBLIC "/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/avr/include/")
target_include_directories(untitled PUBLIC "/Users/david/C/arduino/avr-libstdcpp/include")
```

And I'm getting the following error when trying to run CMake:

```
/Users/david/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp:75:29: error: 'USB_VID' was not declared in this scope
   75 |  D_DEVICE(0xEF,0x02,0x01,64,USB_VID,USB_PID,0x100,IMANUFACTURER,IPRODUCT,ISERIAL,1);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or where I can find decent information on how to build Arduino without the IDE?

Comment: possibly related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/44577/326729, https://community.platformio.org/t/pro-micro-atmega32u4-usb-vid-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/29949, https://github.com/tobozo/WUD-Ducky/issues/4

Comment: Your handling device is odd. If you want code for an ATmega2560, use `-mmcu=atmega2560`. For an ATmega16U2, use `-mmcu=atmega16u2`. These devices have different capabilities, different `<avr/io.h>` attached to them, and belong to different multilib-sets.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Debian's package for Arduino `arduino-core-avr`, there is a file `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt`, containing:

```
build.usb_flags=-DUSB_VID={build.vid} -DUSB_PID={build.pid}
```

which in turn is referenced in a file called `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/boards.txt`

At the top of platform.txt is a link [Platform specification](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/platform-specification/)
describing both platform.txt and boards.txt.
One section is about [Board VID/PID](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.32/platform-specification/#board-vidpid)

> **Board VID/PID**
>
> USB vendor IDs (VID) and product IDs (PID) identify USB devices to the computer.

So it looks like you can just add the appropriate defines to your compiler flags, e.g.

```
-DUSB_VID=0x1234 -DUSB_PID=0x5678
```

The specific ids depend on the USB device you have on your Arduino board.