# CMake and strange behavior when invoking custom function

Tags: c++, cmake

I have big project. In root directory I've created file `CMake\optionalsource.cmake` (in directory `CMake` are other helper files), which contains this function definitions:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
# cmake_parse_arguments needs cmake 3.5

##
# This function always adds sources to target, but when "WHEN" condition is not meet
# source is excluded from build process.
# This doesn't break build, but source is always visible for the project, what is 
# very handy when working with muti-platform project with sources needed
# only for specific platform
#
# Usage:
#      target_optional_sources(WHEN <condition> 
#                              TARGET <target>
#                              <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items2...]
#                              [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items2...] ...])
##
function(target_optional_sources)
    set(options OPTIONAL "")
    set(oneValueArgs WHEN TARGET)
    set(multiValueArgs PUBLIC PRIVATE INTERFACE)

    cmake_parse_arguments(target_optional_sources 
                          "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}"
                          ${ARGN})

    # for debugging purposes 
    message("TARGET ${target_optional_sources_TARGET}")
    message("PUBLIC ${target_optional_sources_PUBLIC}")
    message("PRIVATE ${target_optional_sources_PRIVATE}")
    message("INTERFACE ${target_optional_sources_INTERFACE}")
    message("WHEN ${target_optional_sources_WHEN} ${${target_optional_sources_WHEN}}")

    target_sources(${target_optional_sources_TARGET}
                   PUBLIC ${target_optional_sources_PUBLIC}
                   PRIVATE ${target_optional_sources_PRIVATE}
                   INTERFACE ${target_optional_sources_INTERFACE})

    if (NOT ${target_optional_sources_WHEN})

        set_source_files_properties(${target_optional_sources_PUBLIC}
                                    PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
        set_source_files_properties(${target_optional_sources_PRIVATE}
                                    PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
        set_source_files_properties(${target_optional_sources_INTERFACE}
                                    PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)

    endif(NOT ${target_optional_sources_WHEN})

endfunction(target_optional_sources)
```

This is included into a root `CMakeLists.txt`. 
Now this function quite simple. It was motivated by [this nice SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973278/1387438) and [this feature request for CMake](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=7835).

Now I've encounter some strange problem.
My project contains many targets (libs/dlls/execs), I used this function in one place like this:

```
add_library(CommonLibrary STATIC
    <list of mutliplatform sources>
)  

message("=== function CommonLibrary ===")
target_optional_sources(WHEN APPLE 
                        TARGET  CommonLibrary
                        PUBLIC
                                macos/CFUtils.cpp
                                macos/CFUtils.h
                                MacMachineData.mm
                                MacMachineData.h
                                macos/MacAutoreleasePool.mm
                                macos/MacAutoreleasePool.h
                        )
```

And in logs I can see this:

```
1>=== function CommonLibrary ===
1>TARGET CommonLibrary
1>PUBLIC macos/CFUtils.cpp;macos/CFUtils.h;MacMachineData.mm;MacMachineData.h;macos/MacAutoreleasePool.mm;macos/MacAutoreleasePool.h
1>PRIVATE
1>INTERFACE
1>WHEN APPLE
```

But lower I can see this error messages:

```
1>CMake Error at SomeOtherLib1/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_executable):
1>  Cannot find source file:
1>
1>    macos/CFUtils.cpp
1>
1>  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
1>  .hpp .hxx .in .txx
1>
1>
1>CMake Error at SomeOtherLib2/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_executable):
1>  Cannot find source file:
1>
1>    macos/CFUtils.cpp
1>
1>  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
1>  .hpp .hxx .in .txx
1>
1>
1>CMake Error at UnitTests/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_executable):
1>  Cannot find source file:
1>
1>    macos/CFUtils.cpp
1>
1>  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
1>  .hpp .hxx .in .txx
1>
```

`macos/CFUtils.cpp` was added only by invoking my custom function, so how it is possible that other `CMakeLists.txt` files has been impacted by successful  function invocation? When I reorder files in function invocation error messages are following this change.

What is more strange under Visual Studio this errors are coursing error report, but project files are regenerated successfully and everything works. I can't live this as it is since it will cause build issue on Jenkins machine.

---

**Edit**:

This is how `CommonLibrary` is linked to other targets, for example:

```
add_executable(TestApp
    <Test app sources>
)

target_link_libraries(TestApp
    PRIVATE
        fmt::fmt-header-only
        CommonLibrary
        SomeOtherLibrary
)
```

Comment: It could be possible that `CommonLibrary` is an [OBJECT library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_library.html#object-libraries), and it is used by other executables as `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:CommonLibrary>`. Anywhere, the problem is unlikely with a custom function, but with a way how do you use `CommonLibrary` in your executables. But you don't show the corresponded code...

Comment: Yes `CommonLibrary` is something everyone are depend on. I will check how other targets are referring to it.

Comment: I've provided extra information. Yes `CommonLibrary` is and object library. I was sure problem is caused by function since when doing this manually (without function) it just works.

Comment: For add source files to the library you eventually use `target_source(PUBLIC)` command. Option `PUBLIC` means that given source files will be "consumed" by other targets who links given library. Exactly this is observed according to the error messages. What is seemed to be wrong for you?

Comment: BTW, the line `set(options OPTIONAL "")` looks weird: you define **two options** with it: 1. The one named `OPTIONAL` 2. The other is an empty string.

Comment: @Tsyvarev good call, changing it to `PRIVATE` solves the problem. I have to read this in details how this `PUBLIC`/`PRIVATE`/`INTERFACE` works. Probably headers suppose to be public and cpp-s private.