# CMake target_sources() for larger library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a larger library, which we now want to build with cmake.

The structure is somewhat like this:

```
foo/
- CMakeLists.txt
- include/
-- foo/
--- utils/
---- utils.hpp
--- foo.hpp
- src/
-- utils/
--- utils.cpp
-- foo.cpp
```

And the root `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(foo CXX)

target_include_directories(
  foo
  PUBLIC
    include
  PRIVATE
    src
)

target_sources(
  foo
  PRIVATE
    src/foo.cpp
    src/utils/utils.cpp
)
```

The problem im seeing now is  that the `target_sources()` call will become very unreadable and error prone the more source files are added.

Ive read about `GLOB` but also read that it is bad practice nowadays.

Whats solutions do you normaly use for libraries like this?

Comment: `target_sources` can be used multiple times, so you can group sources in preferred manner. Some time ago I used this to create [target_optional_sources function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52589309/1387438) with a great results..

Comment: The solutions are to GLOB or to not GLOB. Make your choice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1027247/1387438

Comment: You could list sources in variables. (This also comes in handy, if you want to use different `source_group`s for them.) `set(SOURCES src/foo.cpp ...) set(SOURCES_UTIL src/utils/utils.h ...) target_sources(foo PRIVATE ${SOURCES} ${SOURCES_UTIL})`. Furthermore cmake outputs the name of a source it cannot find, so fixing the source names is trivial.